# Java Socket programming with GUI

Tags: java, sockets, user-interface

i have write a code of GUI, and i want to make it as server client. how do i put the GUI code inside socket class? do i need to make a separate class for GUI or just put it inside socket server class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Classes` are forms of subdivision provided for simplifying your files. There is no right or wrong way to do it. As far as you are concerned with `Server-side GUI`, it is just like normal GUI, but uses input from the socket. So, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: sry if this sounds weird. If i want to put the gui code inside the client socket code, do i need to put it before try{ or inside try{ ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter unless your GUI is wrapped inside a method or its own class.

Comment: So Id say inside try{ just incase there are any local variables